# How to change the instance type in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I am having `m3.xlarge` instance type, but I want to change it to `t1.micro`. I have stopped the server and trying to change the `instace type` by right click on the instance name .

But when I click on submit  to change the server name, I am getting an error in console :

```
POST https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/modify-instance-attribute 400 (Bad Request)
```

When I elaborate it into the network then The response that I got from the server was :

```
{"errors":[{"service":"AmazonEC2","action":"ModifyInstanceAttribute","endPoint":"https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com","statusCode":400,"message":"Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type.","errorCode":"InvalidParameterCombination","errorType":"Unknown","requestId":"28025a27-4c3c-452c-8f04-fc4adc8eb335","serviceResponse":{"Response":{"Errors":{"Error":{"Code":"InvalidParameterCombination","Message":"Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type."}},"RequestID":"28025a27-4c3c-452c-8f04-fc4adc8eb335"}}}],"error":"Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type."}
```

How can I resolve this problem, or how can I change the instance from `xlarge` to `micro`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For whatever reason, Amazon's HVM based AMI is not compatible with the t1.micro size.

Amazon has hardware virtual machine (HVM) based AMIs, and paravirtual machine (PVM) based AMIs. From that error message, AWS is saying that your current instance is HVM based, and t1.micro size will only support PVM based instances.

The way round this would be to create a new AMI from your instance and launch a new instance from that AMI as t1.micro size. Be careful, though, this may just create an HVM-based AMI, in which case you will need to snapshot the volume for your current instance and create a new AMI from that.

Some more information on HVM:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using_cluster_computing.html#concepts_cluster_compute_hvmAMI
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Does_use_of_Cluster_Compute_Instances_differ_from_other_Amazon_EC2_instance_types

Comment: Interestingly the new t2 family, launched yesterday, which replaces the t1 and part of the m1 families, supports only HVM. Amazon claims that HVM performance now surpasses PV performance due to better drivers. http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/low-cost-burstable-ec2-instances/

Comment: "...snapshot the volume for your current instance and create a new AMI from that". Has anyone successfully done this?  I tried it in the opposite direction: created a new HVM-based AMI using my PVM snapshots (wanting to migrate from t1 to t2), but my HVM instance created from that failed to start. Documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/615188/aws-t1-to-t2-migration-client-instanceinitiatedshutdown-on-new-t2-instance). If someone's done it, I'd love some step-by-step instructions!

Comment: I ran into this error using the `kitchen-ec2` gem and found that using `flavor_id: c3.large` for my `driver:` config setting fixed it.    Essentially this answer sums the problem up:   Try a different EC2 instance flavor that supports the HVM AMI.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by matching the instance types. You need to make sure that the instance types for AMI and EC2 are same.